# Dexie.js: Table.where() errors with "Cannot read property 'bound' of undefined"

Tags: typescript, indexeddb, dexie

I'm having some troubles getting where() statements to work in Dexie.  My attempts to use where result in the following error:

```
  console.warn node_modules/dexie/dist/dexie.js:1273
    Unhandled rejection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bound' of undefined
        at makeIDBKeyRange (node_modules/dexie/src/dbcore/dbcore-indexeddb.ts:112:21)
        at node_modules/dexie/src/dbcore/dbcore-indexeddb.ts:314:31
...
```

Here's the code that I used:

```
import Dexie from "dexie";
// @ts-ignore there is not a type for the fake indexeddb
import indexedDB from 'fake-indexeddb';

class TestDatabase extends Dexie {
  constructor() {
    super("test");
    this.version(1).stores({
      data: "id, name"
    });
  }
}

test("dexie", async ()=>{
  Dexie.dependencies.indexedDB = indexedDB;
  const db = new TestDatabase();
  await db.table("data").put({id: "x", name: "xname"});
  const x=await db.table("data").get("x");
  expect (x.name).toEqual("xname");

  const x2=await db.table("data").where("id").equals("x").toArray()
  expect (x2[0].name).toEqual("xname");
})
```

The test appears to be failing at the call to toArray().  How can I get this test to pass?

Comment: Try removing `.toArray()` it looks like that's for passing a callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing to set Dexie.dependencies.IDBKeyRange also.

Fake-indexeddb recommends to do the following to integrate fake-indexeddb in node:

```
const Dexie = require("dexie");
require("fake-indexeddb/auto");

const db = new Dexie("MyDatabase");
```

See [their docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fake-indexeddb#with-dexie-and-other-indexeddb-api-wrappers)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @David.  The docs landed me to this solution.  It runs without error:

```
import Dexie from "dexie";
// @ts-ignore there is not a type for the fake indexeddb
import indexedDB from 'fake-indexeddb';

class TestDatabase extends Dexie {
  constructor() {
    const IDBKeyRange=require("fake-indexeddb/lib/FDBKeyRange");
    super("test",{
      indexedDB: indexedDB,
      IDBKeyRange: IDBKeyRange,
    });
    this.version(1).stores({
      data: "id, name"
    });
  }
}


test("dexie", async ()=>{
  const db = new TestDatabase();
  await db.table("data").put({id: "x", name: "xname"});
  const x=await db.table("data").get("x");
  expect (x.name).toEqual("xname");

  const x2=await db.table("data").where("id").equals("x").toArray();
  expect (x2[0].name).toEqual("xname");
})
```

Comment: Great. Your solution is less obtrusive than require("fake-indexeddb/auto").